# WiX Burn Theme checkbox - making it checked by default

Tags: checkbox, wix

I've added a checkbox to the pre-existing WixBootstrapper theme in the options page:

```
<Checkbox Name="MyCheckbox" X="11" Y="217" Width="17" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes" />
```

In my bundle I pass the value of this checkbox through to the MSI:

```
<MsiPackage DisplayInternalUI="no" SourceFile="..\WixInstaller\bin\$(var.Configuration)\myinstaller.msi" Id="MainPackage">
<MsiProperty Name="INSTALLDIR" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
<MsiProperty Name="CHECKED" Value="[MyCheckbox]" />
```

This works fine, except I want the Checkbox to be checked by default.

I've seen solutions where you define:

```
<Property Id="myprop" Value="1" />
```

and change the Checkbox to have a `Property="myprop"` attribute.

Adding any `<Property>` element to the burn theme seems to break it **(.exe won't run after building)**.

Answer (score 9):

I finally found the answer [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Re-How-to-set-Checkbox-selected-by-default-in-Wix-bootstrapper-P-td7593010.html).

You set a variable in your Bundle with the same name as your checkbox:

```
<Bundle ...>
    <Variable Name="MyCheckbox" Type="numeric" Value="1" />
```

I've never been so happy to see a checkbox checked!